# How can i validate a non editable field using Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

How can i validate the non-editable field using selenium?

Plese provide me a command and example for the above scenario.

Comment: what did you try? Please try with `verifyElementPresent`. Non editable fields may have `readonly` as one of attributes.

Comment: Please provide the HTML code including the field you are trying to validate and examples of what you have tried already, stack overflow is a problem solving service, not a code writing one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more details ... In what language ? 
What properties are available on the field ?

in pseudocode you'll do something like (if it has an ID attribute):

```
WebDriver->findBy( WebDriver::id('my_field'))->isEnabled()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `verifyEditable` or `verifyNotEditable` command.

Check out this link for more info.
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2013/07/using-verifyeditable-and.html